# Configure isort to not touch already existing sections but only sort within sections

Tags: python, isort

I want to configure `isort` such that it doesn't touch my sections but only sorts within sections alphabetically or according to some other parameter. Namely I want it to turn:

```
import z
import a

from my.package.b import thing
from my.package.a import other
```

into:

```
import a
import z

from my.package.a import other
from my.package.b import thing
```

or any other readable ordering. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you read https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/custom_sections_and_ordering.html ?

Comment: @flakes yes and I don't want to painstakingly enumerate all packages that I might use in a configuration somewhere. I just want isort to not touch the sections I already have in a file.

Comment: To clarify, I think what you're asking is how to get isort to only sort each section and never move imports between sections. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can set the `force_alphabetical_sort_within_sections` option to true to accomplish this. ([isort configuration options](https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/options.html#force-alphabetical-sort-within-sections))